# How to confirm local printer pops up dialog to proceed the printing job (Chrome printing)

Tags: python, google-chrome, printing, confirm

I try to directly print the information by Chrome.
The final step I stuck as the picture shows, I have no idea on how to click the confirmation button.

The window handle doesn't work since this confirmation message isn't a 'window'. Could someone teach me how to directly choose this message box and click the "Print" button? Thank you!
[Pops up message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PumkC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve this issue by the following code, main concept is that you don't need to press the confirm button, but just disable the print preview function of Chrome. Hope this will also help someone in the future.
(You just need to put the option setting as below when you use selenium package)

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing') # Disable chrome's print preview
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'Your path\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```